# how to convert null into 0 when doing Sqoop export

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop, bigdata

I am trying to export a hive table to MySQL. This hive table has a lot nulls in it.

We would like to convert these nulls into 0 when we are doing sqoop export.

`--input-null-string <null-string>` and `--input-null-non-string <null-string>` would not help because these two will interpret specified strings as null for string columns or non-string columns. What we want is the reverse way, convert null into 0 when doing an export.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create another table in Hive, replacing all nulls to zeros with [COALESCE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions) function. And this table will be used as a datasource for export.

Comment: I am doing export not import, sqoop export doesn't have "query" parameter.

Comment: @S.Stas Edit your answer or delete it.